# Constructor Function and Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Nokta{
    private:
        int x,y;

    public:
        Nokta();
        Nokta(int, int);

        int getX();
        int getY();

        void setX(int);
        void setY(int);

      

};


Nokta::Nokta(){
    cout << "parametresiz kurucu cagrildi\n";
}


Nokta::Nokta(int x, int y=0){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    cout << "parametreli kurucu cagrildi\n";
}

int Nokta::getX(){
    return x;
}
int Nokta::getY(){
    return y;
}
void Nokta::setX(int _x){
    x=_x;
}
void Nokta::setY(int _y){
    if(_y > 5)
        y=_y;
    else
        y = 2;
}

int main(){  
 
    Nokta *ptr;
    cout  << ptr << " " << &ptr << " "<< ptr->getX() << endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

Nokta* ptr; A constructor function is not called when I type it, but I can print one of its variables to the screen. ptr->getX() works. I guess this value is randomly assigned, but how is it done in the background before an object is created?

Output
`0x401b6b 0x61ff0c 1528349827`

Comment: `ptr` is uninitialized, so `ptr->getX()` has **undefined behavior**.

Comment: It has _undefined behavior_, meaning that there is no guarantee how the program will behave. It could do anything for any reason or none. Btw. already printing `ptr` is undefined behavior, because `ptr` is not initialized to any value.

Comment: Yes, the constructor won't be called, because you're just declaring a pointer to Nokta class. If you want the constructor to be called, allocate some memory to it using `new` operator.

Comment: `Nokta *ptr;` does not allocate a `Nokta`. Try `Nokta n;` `cout << n.getX() << endl;` instead. That also has _undefined behavior_ though since you haven't initialized `x` in the default constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ function called without object initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360501/c-function-called-without-object-initialization), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963735/why-doesnt-accessing-an-uninitialized-pointer-display-an-error?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278139/object-creation-differences?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is just a variable that *should* hold an address to a `Nokta` object. But you did not create a `Nokta` object for the pointer to point to.

`Nokta noktaObj = Nokta(someNum, someNum)`

`Nokta* ptr = &noktaObj`

When you don't initialize the object, and try to access data (like `ptr->getX()`), you're just getting whatever garbage happens to be in memory in that location.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `new` returns a pointer. Also, there is no guarantee that accessing the pointer will produce some garbage value. The program might just as well crash or consistently produce a value of `0`. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, my mistake I did not mean to add the `new` statement.

Comment: That is correct, it is undefined behavior. I didn't want to use any terms like that as it seems like OP is still green, just wanted to explain conceptually what is happening. It is undefined because you are accessing memory that has not been initialized. Basically grabbing some leftover garbage in the memory that can do anything to your program.